# How to match the + symbol in the URL with Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter (IIRF)?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iirf

I have this rule for a redirect

```
RedirectRule ^/test+test.html /index.html [I,R=301]
```

and the index.html file exists in the root/ of the website however when I visit mysite/test+test.html I get a 404 error, maybe the plus (+) character need to be matched in another way, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`+` is special regex symbol meaning 1 or matches. Escape it as:

```
RedirectRule ^/test\+test.html /index.html [I,R=301]
```

Comment: Oh ok try: `RedirectRule "^/test test.html" /index.html [I,R=301]`

Comment: no, it does not work. I tried also with ^/test\xtest.html and ^/test\x20test.html My IIRF version is the latest 2.1

Comment: Hmm can you try adding `UrlDecoding Off` in your INI file? And then retest.

Comment: also with "UrlDecoding OFF" in INI file does not work. I tried also with a rule like "RedirectRule ^/test([^/]+)*   / [I,R=301]" to get all the occurrences that starts with "/test" but it fail again. I'm sad! just a note: the server is a 64bit and it's running 32bit version of IIRF.